# How to keep lines together in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have these lines in my (technical) document:

```
public IQueryable<NatuurlijkPersoon> Get()

public Person Get(Guid id)

public void Add(Person source, MyEntities context)

public bool SetContext(MyEntities context)
```

*Each line is separated by a single <kbd>Enter</kbd>.*

These have to stay together at all times, line breaking in any way would make the context very hard to understand. So, I've tried the following:

1. Select lines
2. Right click
3. Paragraph
4. Line and Page Breaks tab
5. Keep lines together

It's basically the same as the third option provided on [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/three-simple-ways-to-keep-word-text-together/).

But no effect, they are spread across two pages as before. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"keep lines together" is applied only **within paragraphs**.

In your case you need to use **keep with next**. (take care not to select last line for this action, otherwise this whole part also will be kept together with anything after it)

Comment: So easy, thanks! I figured it would create a paragraph (symbols) this way, but guess not.

Comment: Major upvote for "`take care not to select last line for this action`" - I have been getting that wrong for decades. You just made my Monday !